# CSVReader - Fields do not exist in the CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I'm using the CSVHelper NuGet package and am getting the error "Fields do not exist in CSV file." Here is my code:

```
using (TextReader prodFile = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(prodFile);
    List<PulProduct> prodList = csv.GetRecords<PulProduct>().ToList();
}
```

**class**

```
public class PulProduct
    {
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string PPartNumber { get; set; }
        public string VPartNumber { get; set; }
        public string VPPartNumber { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal ORetail { get; set; }
        public decimal CSRetail { get; set; }
        public decimal BDPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal YDPrice { get; set; }
        public string Hazardous { get; set; }
        public string TruckPart { get; set; }
        public string PartAddDate { get; set; }
        public int AvailabilityWI { get; set; }
        public int AvailabilityNY { get; set; }
        public int AvailabilityTX { get; set; }
        public int AvailabilityCA { get; set; }
        public int AvailabilityNV { get; set; }
        public int AvailabilityNC { get; set; }
        public int AvailabilityNational { get; set; }
        public string Trademark { get; set; }
        public string AdPolicy { get; set; }
        public string PriceChanged { get; set; }
        public string UOM { get; set; }
        public string UPC { get; set; }
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public string Closeout { get; set;}
        public string NoShipToCA { get; set; }
        public string Notes {get; set; }
    }
```

CSVHelper documentation says that CSVHelper will automatically map my class to the CSV file. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

The full exception is:

> An exception of type 'CsvHelper.CsvMissingFieldException' occurred in CsvHelper.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Fields 'PartNumber' do not exist in the CSV file.

Here is a sample header and first line:

```
Part Number,Punctuated Part Number,Vendor Part Number,Vendor Punctuated Part Number,Part Status,Part Description,Original Retail,Current Suggested Retail,Base Dealer Price,Your Dealer Price,Hazardous Code,Truck Part Only,Part Add Date,WI Availability,NY Availability,TX Availability,CA Availability,NV Availability,NC Availability,National Availability,Trademark,Ad Policy,Price Changed Today,Unit of Measure,UPC Code,Brand Name,Country of Origin,Weight,Closeout Catalog Indicator,NoShipToCA, Notes
0023451,001-0901,0067401,067-0401,S,4-1 SYS OBR CB350/4,399.95,352.95,384.40,214.40,,,19341102,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,N,EA,879345348000086,MAC,US,13.80,N, ,
```

Comment: You should post sample csv data like the header and first line of data.

Comment: Show the exception too, please (for stack trace, only include relevant lines).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your field names and your file column headers do not match due to whitespace.  In PulProduct, the first field is "PartNumber".  In your sample file, the first column us "Part Number".  Setting **IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace** to true in the CsvConfiguration object will handle this.

```
using (TextReader prodFile = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(prodFile);
    csv.Configuration.IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace = true;
    List<PulProduct> prodList = csv.GetRecords<PulProduct>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: This option no longer exists sadly.

Comment: thare are the 'csv.Configuration.IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace' option!

Comment: You'll now have to use the `PrepareHeaderForMatch` function:
`csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (s, i) => s.Replace(" ", string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation states that CSVHelper will automatically map the class to the CSV file, you still need to manually write a map that will map to CSV file.